# How to edit the order of LastName, FirstName in pandas without losing the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in which two columns have strings values "LastName, FirstName". I would love to replace them with "FirstName Last Name". They are like these:

```
      conductorName        composerName  conduct_count
0  Abbado, Claudio         Berg,  Alban                2
1  Abbado, Claudio     Berlioz,  Hector                1
2  Abbado, Claudio  Bernstein,  Leonard                1
3  Abbado, Claudio    Brahms,  Johannes                2
4  Abbado, Claudio     Bruckner,  Anton                1
```

I have tried:
`data = [" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in data["composerName"]]`

This nicely gives me a list of composerName but now I lose the pandas dataframe (here is the error  `----> 1 data.head()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'`)

I have also tried:
`for n in data["composerName"]:
    " ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1])`

However, this does not change the order of LastName and FirstName

I would love to keep the pandas dataframe for analysis. I appreciate any assistance. Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps `data['conductorName'] = data['conductorName'].str.replace(',', '')`

Comment: Thank you. This is fast and works very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the vectorised `str.split` to split on the separator, then reverse the list contents using slicing semantics and then join again using `str.join`:

```
In [35]:
df['ComposerFirstLastName'] = df['composerName'].str.split(', ').str[::-1].str.join(' ')
df['ConductorFirstLastName'] = df['conductorName'].str.split(', ').str[::-1].str.join(' ')
df
Out[35]:
          composerName        conductorName  conductor_count   FirstLastName  \
index                                                                          
0      Abbado, Claudio         Berg,  Alban                2  Claudio Abbado   
1      Abbado, Claudio     Berlioz,  Hector                1  Claudio Abbado   
2      Abbado, Claudio  Bernstein,  Leonard                1  Claudio Abbado   
3      Abbado, Claudio    Brahms,  Johannes                2  Claudio Abbado   
4      Abbado, Claudio     Bruckner,  Anton                1  Claudio Abbado   

      ComposerFirstLastName ConductorFirstLastName  
index                                               
0            Claudio Abbado             Alban Berg  
1            Claudio Abbado         Hector Berlioz  
2            Claudio Abbado      Leonard Bernstein  
3            Claudio Abbado        Johannes Brahms  
4            Claudio Abbado         Anton Bruckner
```

Answer (score 1):

You rewrote over the the entire dataframe:

```
data = [" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in data["composerName"]]
```

This is what it *should* say:

```
data["composerName"] = [" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in data["composerName"]]
```